# How to fetch users added in Android devices?

Tags: android

I want to fetch names of the user account's added in android device programmatically. For details go through the attached below image

[image]

I have tried below code

```
 AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getActivity()); // "this" references the current Context
      //  Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
        Account[] accounts =am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            name = accounts[0].name;
        } else {
            name = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        }
```

Comment: Good work with the edit! The code looks as if it should work. What's going wrong?

Comment: are you trying to fetch from local DB?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want [DevicePolicyManager#getSecondaryUsers()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getSecondaryUsers(android.content.ComponentName)).

You will need to have Device Administrator access: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin